Validar registro existente de base datos en Oracle Apex
Buenas Tardes Comunidad.
Agradezco su ayuda en indicarme como valido un registro que ya existe en base de datos en Oracle Apex.
Esta es la tabla de Usuarios
CREATE TABLE RH_CLINICA.Usuario (
  ID_Usuario NUMBER(10) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE CACHE 20),
  Nombre_Usuario VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  Contrasena VARCHAR2(60) NOT NULL,
  Estado_Usuario NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  Fecha_Registro DATE NULL,
  Adicionado_Por VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  Fecha_Modifica DATE NULL,
  Modificado_Por VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_Usuario
    PRIMARY KEY (ID_Usuario));

Por otro lado hice una función en base de datos para que me retorne si existe o no en este caso el nombre de usuario ya que el sistema no va permitir que exista el dato duplicado, detallo la función.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RH_PRC_VALIDAR_USUARIO (
    pNombreUsuario IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
    v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
    -- Realiza la consulta para contar los usuarios con el nombre proporcionado
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_count
    FROM RH_CLINICA.USUARIO
    WHERE Nombre_Usuario = pNombreUsuario;

    -- Devuelve TRUE si el nombre de usuario ya existe
    IF v_count > 0 THEN    
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE; -- Devuelve FALSE si el nombre de usuario no existe
    END IF;
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        -- Manejo de excepciones
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error al validar usuario: ' || SQLERRM);
        RETURN FALSE; -- Devuelve FALSE en caso de error para no confundir con una validación exitosa
END RH_PRC_VALIDAR_USUARIO;

A nivel de oracle apex lo replique ya sea en una validación o proceso, en el momento que registro un usuario por ejemplo "yorle22" y vuelvo a registrar el mismo nombre usuario, la función o en oracle apex no determina la validación.
Detallo el proceso en Oracle Apex
DECLARE
    v_is_valid BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
    -- Llamar a la función para validar el nombre de usuario
    v_is_valid := RH_PRC_VALIDAR_USUARIO(:P1_NOMBRE_USUARIO);

    IF v_is_valid THEN
        -- Mostrar un mensaje de error si el nombre de usuario ya existe
        apex_error.add_error(
            p_message => 'El nombre de usuario ya existe.',
            p_display_location => apex_error.c_inline_in_notification,
            p_page_item_name => 'P1_NOMBRE_USUARIO'
        );
        -- Previene el envío del formulario
        :P1_VALIDATION_STATUS := 'ERROR';
    ELSE
        -- Permitir el envío del formulario si el nombre de usuario es válido
        :P1_VALIDATION_STATUS := 'VALIDO';
    END IF;
END;


Agradezco nuevamente su ayuda si saben que alternativa o una alguna opción para poder resolver el inconveniente.
Saludos
